# Get the internal names of User Profile activities 'Blog Posts' and 'Blog Comments under 'Activities I am following'

Tags: 2010, powershell, sharepoint-server, user-profile-property

I am using a PowerShell Script (dont remember the link from where i referenced this) that updates (Checks/Unchecks) the activities under 'Activities I am following'. I also ran a script to get the internal names of all the activities listed. Say there are 30 in my farm, I got 15.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ActivityTypes>
     <URL>https://workspacestest.brookfield.com/</URL>
     <ActivityType Name="StatusMessage" IsSet="False"></ActivityType>
     <ActivityType Name="BlogUpdate" IsSet="False"></ActivityType>
</ActivityTypes>
```

Here is the script:

```
#----------------Get the xml file---------------------------------------------------------------

    [xml]$xmlData=Get-Content "UpdateUserActivitiesFeed.xml"

    #----------------Set Activity Feed Preferences--------------------------------------------------
    function SetActivityFeed
    {
    Param(
    [Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager]$UserActivityManager,
    [string]$User
    )

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try
    {
       $apptList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityPreferencePerType]
       $appts = $UserActivityManager.ActivityPreferences.GetActivityPreferencesPerType()

       $ats = $UserActivityManager.ActivityTypes

       $User >> ".\ActivityTypeName.txt"

       foreach($appt in $appts)
       {
          $appt.ActivityType.ActivityTypeName >> ".\ActivityTypeName.txt"
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     # IsSet -> indicating whether a user wants to see the ActivityType object stored
     # in this ActivityPreferencePerType in a feed
     #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          $appt.IsSet >> ".\ActivityTypeName.txt"
     #----------------------------------------------
     # Change the value of IsSet to check/uncheck
     #----------------------------------------------
          $xmlData.ActivityTypes.ActivityType | ForEach-Object{
             $typeName = $_.Name
             if($appt.ActivityType.ActivityTypeName.Equals($typeName))
             {
                $appt.IsSet = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($_.IsSet)
             #write-host -f red "Check ActivityType: " $appt.ActivityType.ActivityTypeName}
             } 
          }
          $apptList.Add($appt)

       } 
    ### Display value of properties
    <#
     foreach($type in $ats)
     {
     write-host -f green "ActivityTypeNameLocStringName:" $type.ActivityTypeNameLocStringName
     write-host -f blue "ActivityTypeNameLocStringResourceFile:" $type.ActivityTypeNameLocStringResourceFile
     write-host -f red "ApplicationId:" $type.ApplicationId
     }
     #>
    }
    catch
    {
       Get-Date >> ".\ActivityFeedErrLog.txt"
       $_.Exception.ToString() >> ".\ActivityFeedErrLog.txt"
    }

    $line = "--------------------------------------"
    $line >> ".\ActivityTypeName.txt"
    ### Sets the current user's preferences for each ActivityType object managed by the ActivityManager
    $UserActivityManager.ActivityPreferences.SetActivityPreferencesPerType($apptList)
    $UserActivityManager.ActivityPreferences.Commit()
    $UserActivityManager.ActivityPreferences.Refresh()

    }

    #----------------Get Activity Manager with specific user account------------------------------------------
    function ConfigActivityFeed()
    {
       $snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
       if ($snapin -eq $null)
       {
          Write-Host "`nLoading SharePoint Powershell Snapin`n"
          Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
       }

    Try
    {
       $site = Get-SPSite $xmlData.ActivityTypes.URL
       $context = Get-SPServiceContext($site)
     ### Get User Profile
       $upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

       [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System")
       $user = $upm.GetUserProfile("bmsl\mjoshi")
     ### Iterate all the user profiles
     <#[System.Collections.IEnumerator] $en = $upm.GetEnumerator()
     while($en.MoveNext())
     {
     $user = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile]($en.Current)
     $str = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName
     $userName = $user[$str].Value.ToString()
     write-host -f blue $userName
     #>
     ### Get Activity Feed Manager
        $am = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager($user, $context)

     ### Using reflection to set preference for user; otherwise, only get preference of account which is used to login server
        $methodInfo = $am.GetType().GetMethod("CopyBasicUserInfo", [reflection.bindingflags]"nonpublic,instance", $null, $user.GetType(), $null)
     ### Invokes the method represented by the current object instance, using the specified parameters
     ### Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
        $methodInfo.Invoke($am, $user)

        SetActivityFeed -UserActivityManager $am -User $userName
     #}
    }
    Catch
    {
       write-error $_.Exception
       Get-Date >> ".\ActivityFeedErrLog.txt"
       $_.Exception.ToString() >> ".\ActivityFeedErrLog.txt"
    }

    write-host -f red "Done"
    $site.Dispose()

    }

    #----- Call function ---

    ConfigActivityFeed
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 50;
```

My problem is I am able to update activities like StatusMessage, Birthday_Reminder, SharingInterest etc... I want to update 'Blog Posts' and 'Blog Comments'. I need to know the internal name that PowerShell recognizes so that I can give it as an input in my XML.